# Should I bounty one of these to get a canonical answer for Catalina era hardware?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, exact-duplicates, canonical-questions

There are quite a few versions of “I want an external display, an open clamshell and no display whatsoever” questions:

- [How to automatically turn black main monitor when external monitor is connected while using internal keyboard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/376161/how-to-automatically-turn-black-main-monitor-when-external-monitor-is-connected)
- [How do I turn off laptop display when I have an external display?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21729/how-do-i-turn-off-laptop-display-when-i-have-an-external-display)

Is one of these worth getting a great answer or an edit to make it clear?